# Mysql cross-table search

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a search field where users can search for studies that use particular elements.

I have two tables: `elements` and `studies`.

`elements` features relevant elements of the study, such as the author, manipulation, etc. and `studies` features relevant information on the principal investigator, the title of the study, and abstract.

The purpose of this is that sometimes the user wants to check not only if a particular study exists, but if that particular study also uses particular elements. For example, a study can feature a negotiation game with a personal manipulation or a collective manipulation. If the user wants to check if there is a negotiation study that uses collective manipulation, then the study using individual manipulation should not be returned by the query.

I can create a search field where users can search for studies as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){

    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM studies WHERE Author LIKE '%$search%' OR Study_Name LIKE '%$search%'
    OR Abstract LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($queryResult > 1){
    echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>There are ".$queryResult." results.</h1>";}

    elseif ($queryResult < 1) {
        echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>There are ".$queryResult." results.</h1>";
    } else {
        echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>There is ".$queryResult." result.</h1>";
    }

    echo "<br>";

    if ($queryResult > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<div class='w5-study' style='text-align: center;'>
                <hr>
                <table class='w3-table w3-striped w3-border'>
                <tr>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Abstract</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>".$row['Author']."</td>
                <td>".$row['Study_Name']."</td>
                <td>".$row['Abstract']."</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>";
        }
    } else {
    echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Your query returned zero results.</h1>";
    }
```

***EDIT - Thanks to Whirl Mind

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit-advanced-search'])){

    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search-advanced']);

    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM studies S, elements E WHERE S.Studies_Element_ID = E.Elements_Element_ID And (S.Author LIKE '%$search%'
    OR S.Study_Name LIKE '%$search%'
    OR S.Abstract LIKE '%$search%') and (E.Element_Name LIKE '%$search%' OR E.Element_Author LIKE '%$search%'
    OR E.Element_Source LIKE '%$search%' OR E.Element_Manipulation LIKE '%$search%'
    OR E.Element_Scale LIKE '%$search%' OR E.Element_Type LIKE '%$search%')";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);

    $queryResulti = mysqli_num_rows($results);


        if ($queryResulti > 0){


            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

            echo 

            "<div class='w5-study' style='text-align: center;'>
            <hr>
            <table class='w3-table w3-striped w3-border'>
            <tr>
            <th>Principal Investigator</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Abstract</th>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Manipulation</th>
            <th>Scale</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>".$row['Study_ID']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Author']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Study_Name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Abstract']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Element_ID']."</td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            </div>
            ";
            } 
        }

        else {

            echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Your advanced query returned zero results.</h1>";
            }
```

}

However, even if I put in the correct parameters, the code always returns: 
Your advanced query returned zero results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i don't get these lines

`$results = $result.=$resulti;

        $queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($results);`

I might misunderstand but what are they supposed to do.. If you have let's say 3 rows from your first request and 18 from your second request. How do you concatenate these and how are you supposed to count any row numbers for this?

Comment: also you might want to care around this `elseif($queryResult or $queryResulti == 0)` which means `if ($queryResult == true or $queryResulti ==0)`, and not `if ($queryResult == 0 or $queryResulti ==0)`

Comment: what does var_dump of $result show ?

Comment: echo var_dump($results) gives: bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for using a SQL statement that uses a join between the two tables. Somewhat like :

checks if the query returns results for both tables
Option 1 : 
If the requirement is that, the search phrase should be found in both tables :

```
SELECT * FROM studies S, Elements E WHERE E.StudyId = S.StudyId And (S.Author LIKE '%$search%' OR S.Study_Name LIKE '%$search%'  OR S.Abstract LIKE '%$search%')
And (E.Name_Element LIKE '%$search%' OR E.Name_Author LIKE '%$search%'
    OR E.Source LIKE '%$search%' OR E.Manipulation LIKE '%$search%' OR E.Scale LIKE '%$search%')
```

Obviously this assumes you have a field to join them with, a field in the Element table that specifies which field in the Studies table connects to the principal investigator etc.

Option 2:

If your requirement is that the result should return results that are found in "either of the two" tables (people commonly wrongly use 'both' to mean this), then you should use a UNION query of 2 different SQL statements on the two tables, that fetches any fields commonly found in both.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response.I have changed the code to the following: